# how to return true or false for ajax form submission based on data recieved from php file ?

Tags: php, ajax

The form always gets submitted. I want to submit it only if data=="available" , i.e ...the php file returned available.

```
function PostData() {
        var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
        }
        var username = document.getElementById("username_input").value;
        xhr.open('POST', 'header/onsubmit_check.php');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send("username=" + username);


        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                var data=xhr.responseText.trim();
                document.getElementById('onsubmit_feedback').innerHTML = data;
        }

        if (data=='Available') {
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your PHP code? have you tried using console.log(data) to check the actual response in your browser console?

Comment: I m a newbie. I have no idea what console.log(data) is . @koala_dev

Comment: add that line before your if(data=='Available'), then open your browser console (Ctrl+Shift+J) and when you run the ajax call the response will appear there

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll see undefined since data will only get a value when the ajax call is completed, do as @Punnet suggested and move your if inside onreadystatechange and only submit when you get "Available"

Comment: Thanks guys..@puneet's answer has worked great. Can u plz tell me how can i send more varialbles to the same php file  @koala_dev

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7203609/2049063)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML make sure you use form as

```
<form id="my_form" onsubmit="return PostData()">
```

Make few changes in your javascript code

```
function PostData() {
        var xhr,data;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
        }
        var username = document.getElementById("username_input").value;
        xhr.open('POST', 'header/onsubmit_check.php');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send("username=" + username);


        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                data=xhr.responseText.trim();
                document.getElementById('onsubmit_feedback').innerHTML = data;
                if (data==='Available'){
                     document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
                }
        }

        return false;

    }
```

The function always returns `false` and submits the form when ajax returns required value.